# How to fetch elements in which object array exist

Tags: reactjs

[image]

In my react project, the cart is state which I initialize in the reducer.

So I want to fetch only those items in which the object of array present

Ex. From the above image 1st 3 items whose id are 1,2,4 like this

**Existing code

```
 Object.values(this.props.cart).map((item) => {
                  console.log(item);
}
```

Using above code currently it fetch all values including `consulation_date` and `cosultation_time_slot`

But I want to fetch only cart items in which keys are present such as id, title, quantity.....

How can I loop like this to print only 1,2,4...?

Answer (score 0):

You can `.filter` those values. If values which you want to obtain have for example "title" but others which you do not want do not have "title" property you can filter by that property. Instead of using "map" put "filter".

```js
Object.values(this.props.cart).filter(item => item.title)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a new array and make a condition then you can use new array.
for example

```
let arr = [1,2,3,"str", "str2"]
let newArr = arr.filter(v=> typeof(v) === 'number')
console.log(newArr)
```